# Add item to dropdown without refresh

Tags: python, django

[image]

City is a (dropdown in a main form ) with a +(Add) button.

This +(Add) button opens another form in separate window.

[image]

On saving a new city in the second form, I want the new city name to be added in the City dropdown without refreshing the main form.

Here is my code.

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form">
    {% csrf_token %}      
    <td>City: {{ form.city }}
    <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="addCity(event)">+</button>
    </td>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>    
</form>

<script>
    function addCity(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        window.open("/city/", "", "width=500,height=500");
    }
</script>
```

city.html

```
<form method="POST" class="post-form" action="/city/" id="form"> 

  {% csrf_token %} 

  <div class="container">                  
    <div class="form-group row">  
      <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">City:</label>  
      <div class="col-sm-4">  
      {{ form.name }}  
      </div>  
    </div>  

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>      
    </div>  

</form>
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [  
     path('city/', views.add_city, name='city_master'),
]
```

views.py

```
def add_city(request):
    cities = City.objects.all()  

    if request.method == "POST":  
        form = CityForm(request.POST)  
        if form.is_valid():  
            try:  
                form.save()  
                return redirect('/city/')  
            except:  
                pass  
    else:  
        form = CityForm()  
    return render(request,'city.html',{'form':form})
```

Answer (score 2):

I can not comment that is why i am writing here, Sir you need ajax call. Do not use POST request, for all post request the page reloads it self. so try using ajax, you can create a route and function inside controller.

Comment: can you pls give sample code using my example